# re-arrange string for international date time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am calling a library in C# that returns a date and time in a single string format like this

At 3:14 PM on 11/22/2014

or

At 2:00 AM on day 1, 15 of every month, starting 11/23/2014 - Trigger expires at 2/26/2015 12:00:00 AM.

I need it to look like

At 3:14 PM on 22/11/2014

At 2:00 AM on day 1, 15 of every month, starting 23/11/2014 - Trigger expires at 26/2/2015 12:00:00 AM.

How would I modify this string to switch the month and day for so that it will look right for internal users?

Comment: why can't you just have it return the date time or have it use a different format string?

Comment: the best thing to do is have the library rework it.

Comment: Its not my library.  I can't control the format.

Comment: which library is it?

Comment: https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/  I am pulling a task t.Definition like the the example here.  https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples   Task t = ts.GetTask(taskName);
   td = t.Definition;

Comment: since that is open source, you should be able to make the modifications or ask the team to work with you on it.

Comment: It a wraper for a com object

Comment: What call are you making that outputs the string `At 3:14 PM every Saturday of every week, starting 11/22/2014`. It is not obvious from the code example you linked to which call does it.

Comment: TaskService ts = new TaskService();
TaskFolder tf = ts.RootFolder;
foreach (Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task t in tf.Tasks)
            {string myschedule = t.Definition.Triggers[0].ToString();}

Comment: What is the data type of `t.Definition.Triggers[0]`? Maybe don't convert it to a string in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `String.Format`

```
// create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone


// month/day numbers without/with leading zeroes
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);            // "3/9/2008"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"

// day/month names
String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt);    // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"
String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"

// two/four digit year
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt);            // "03/09/08"
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "03/09/2008"
```

**EDIT**

```
var source= "At 3:14 PM on 11/22/2014";
// get the last 10 characters from the string just the DATE
var justDate = source.Substring(source.Length - 10); // justDate = "11/22/2014"
// Parse string justDate to DateTime
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(justDate , "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**EDIT 02**

that's should do it for you

```
const string PATTERN = @"([0-9]){1,2}\/([0-9]){1,2}\/([0-9]){4}";
const string INPUT = "At 2:00 AM on day 1, 15 of every month, starting 11/23/2014 - Trigger expires at 2/26/2015 2/2/2015  02/02/2015 12:00:00 AM";
var correctString = INPUT;
var regex = new Regex(PATTERN);
var match = regex.Match(INPUT);
while (match.Success) {
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Value, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var dt2 = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dt);
    correctString = correctString.Replace(match.Value, dt2);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: Its not a DateTime object. If it was it would be easy.  I need to search the string and then flip day and month values.

Comment: use substring to get the last 10 charactes and then parse it to DateTime

Comment: Thanks but sometimes it shows up in the middle like this  At 2:00 AM on day 1, 15 of every month, starting 11/23/2014 - Trigger expires at 2/26/2015 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: you better use REGEX to match all Date and replace them

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example using regex?  I searched but couldn't find anything that shows replacing the datetime in the middle of a string.

Comment: check the solution in edit 02 above

Comment: Works perfectly.  Much Appreciated!